# Spring @Autowired not suppost to ant build

Tags: spring, ant, autowired

When I use the `@Autowired` for my spring application, without the setter, and I run it with my test class it is working fine.

However, When I build the class into a jar using ant and make a call to this class (which is inside the jar) it is not working. When I code the setter with the `@Autowired` and build the jar using ant and make a call to this it is working.

Can anyone please explain to me what is the difference?

note:- When I build the jar using eclipse tools without ant for that jar, it is working without the setter method.

So please explain to me why is this not working for the ant built jar only, and why ant built classes only need `@Autowired` with the setter method as well?

Comment: When you say not working, what exactly is happening?  Do you get an exception or the dependency is not injected?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you haven't included some XML resources in your jar file.  For annotated auto wiring to work you need to specify your spring XML `<context:annotation-conig />`.  Make sure that the ant jar task includes the same directories as your eclipse project source directories.

Example ant jar task with two source dirs: `src/main/java` containing your .java files and `src/main/resources` containing XML and other config files:

```
<jar ...>
  <fileset dir="src/main">
    <include name="java" />
    <include name="resources" />
  </fileset>
</jar>
```